# ADDING background color to <td>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to give background color too as seen in the code below , already set the imgBox visible to true.

I want also to add background color of the table row that it is going as the code is written in gridline.ascx.cs , and im not too familiar in it. What should i do? and how can i do it?

Thanks!

```
 if (wli.isBoxRequired)
         ((Image)dvLineItems.FindControl("imgBox")).Visible = true;
```

Comment: as the condition for isBoxRequired is already true how can i add more condition to it in order to add background color?

Comment: Add it as a CSS attribute programmatically with the Add() method. Better yet, just create a CSS rule for it.

Comment: There's not enough here to answer that. There's no `td` in your code. Is it a server-side control or just HTML?

Comment: does your `td` have an `id` or `class`? hint hint

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set the background color in code behind means use the below code,
For Example, 
If you have

```
<td id="tableBody">

</td>
```

then:

```
tableBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "yellow");
```

Comment: Is there a way to write the code like the code written below?

Comment: Is there a way to write a code that is written like this??? ((Image)dvLineItems.FindControl("imgBox")).Visible = true;

Comment: can you please explain it to me , what does that mean?